# is it ok to connect 2 devices concurrently to connect Bluetooth in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Iam connecting 3G phone for my Android device for internet connection and another Socket(SPP) for CAN signal receiving.Whenever I manually connect to the Bluetooth tethering via 3G phone, i can browse internet perfectly and speed is good.Whenever programmatically connect to the 3G connection, i couldn't browse internet.i checked in shell and observing that in my mobile 'device is connected' message displayed and E symbol appears.No problem for me to connect Socket.But I got problem to use 3G phone.For this iam using APN/DUN mode.I checked both but no use.Is there any performance issue here or anything wrong to connect different devices by using Bluetooth API in android.Why this happends while connecting Mobile programmatically.Please give me guidance.

Regards,
Rajendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have several open connections at a time.

In fact, I've used my hands-free bluetooth on my phone, as it is connected to my ELM327 SPP device streaming at full speed. I didn't notice any hiccups.

As for losing connectivity when you are connected to multiple devices, it's most likely an issue with the DUN provider you're using.

Also it's worth stating that, on Verizon/3g phones, when you use the phone as a phone, it suspends all 3g data services until the call is terminated.

Answer (score 0):

The way L2CAP defines the LT_ADDR allows connecting devices up to 7. Your connection problems is something else.